# Is there any function which will allow me to take selective lags of ARMA modelling part while doing ARMAX?

Tags: r

I am looking for a function or a method that allows me to use lags selectively in an ARMAX process while doing time series modelling.

To do the ARMA modelling of the data, I’ve used the following function to choose only the selective lags where the ACF/PACF was significant where dal is the time series data for aluminium.

`dal.arma= arma(dal, lag=list(ar=c(1,26),ma=c(1,4,7))) ; summary(dal.arma)`

With the ARMAX function of R, I can’t take selective lags, and the function estimates the coefficients on all the lags in between. Hence the function estimates all 26 lags for AR and all 7 for MA, giving me no freedom to choose lags in between when I want to do ARMAX.

`al.armax= armax(dal, order=c(26,0,7), xreg=xreg) ;`

where xreg is a data.frame type object consisting of lagged series of exogenous variables.
But, I want only `ar1, ar26, ma1, ma4 and ma7` along with the exogenous variables. Any idea how to solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the *forecast package* and it's *auto.arima* function.